# Can I swap my Xbox 360 Harddrives?

Tags: xbox-360

WE are looking at replacing our xbox 360 s console.  It came with a 250 GB hard drive.  If we were to purchase another xbox 360 console (s or e), but it came with a lower GB hard drive, could we transfer our 250 GB hard drive into it?

Comment: [The Xbox S does come with a removable hard drive...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NhALsgzR0M)

Answer (score 6):

That should be fine, but there is a drawback.

Content on an Xbox 360 has two licenses: Device and User.

The User ID is simple. It matches your Xbox Live account, and allows your user to play saves and content assigned to that user.

The Device ID is more complicated. This ID matches whatever Device (aka console) the content was originally purchased on. Save games are not a concern here, only purchases. If the Device ID of a purchase matches the console, then any user on the console can access that content. However if the Device ID is different, then only the original user can play the content as long as they are signed into Xbox Live. Even if you deleted and re-downloaded the content, it will still use the Device ID of whatever console first downloaded the content.

To get around this, you will need to perform a License Transfer on the new console. You can only do this once every 4 months. From [the DRM FAQ](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-360/downloadable-content/download-content)

> If you purchased a new console or had your console repaired, use the license transfer option on your console. Here’s how:
>
> 1. On your console, sign in to Xbox Live using the gamertag that you used to purchase the content.
>
>    - Need to find your Microsoft account and/or password? See Find your Microsoft account email address or password.
> 2. Go to **settings**, and then select **Account**.
>      [image]
> 3. Under **Your Billing Options**, select **License Transfer**.
> 4. Follow the instructions to transfer the content licenses.
> 5. After you transfer the licenses, download the content again to update the local licenses. For information about how to do this, see [How to redownload previously downloaded or purchased content to your Xbox 360](http://support.xbox.com/xbox-360/downloadable-content/redownload-content).
>
> Other profiles can now use content on your console. You can also use the content when you’re not connected to Xbox Live

This should get you set. As long as you follow these instructions to transfer the licensing, there shouldn't be any further issues.

Do note that the original model Xbox 360 uses a different kind of HDD. If you did get one, it wouldn't be compatible. Since you mentioned you will be getting a different model, this shouldn't apply, but I included it for completeness.